# Strange warning of QNetworkSession?

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am trying to download an image from the internet using Qt's `QNetworkManager`, `QNetworkReply` and `QNetworkRequest`.

The downloading is working in a thread pool. And sometimes I got the following warning from Qt:

```
Type conversion already registered from type QSharePointer<QNetworkSession> to type QObject*

QObject::connect: Incompatible sender/receiver arguments QNetworkSessionPrivateImpl::stateChanged(QnetworkSession::State) --> QNetworkSession::stateChanged(QNetworkSession::State)
```

Which is quite strange. Aren't the `QNetworkManager`, `QNetworkReply` and `QNetworkRequest` reentrant?

Comment: Looks like a bug in Qt.